# Google calendar API not returning all canceled events

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, zend-gdata

I'm having a strange problem with the Google Calendar API (through PHP with Zend_Gdata.) On the calendar in question I have several recurring events starting in March:

- 2010-04-19  9:30 - 16:00
- 2010-04-20  10:00 - 15:30
- 2010-04-21  9:30 - 16:00
- 2010-04-22  10:00 - 15:30
- 2010-04-23  9:30 - 12:30

Each of these repeats indefinitely but has exceptions on some days. My problem is that none of the canceled or modified instances are returned by the API after `2010-07-15`. During the week of August 2nd, all 5 of these recurrences are canceled, and they display as such in Google Calendar, but the API does not return exceptions for these days.

I am querying the calendar with the following code:

```
$gc = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);

$query = $gc->newEventQuery();
$query->setUser(/*calendar ID goes here*/);
$query->setVisibility('private');
$query->setProjection('full');
$query->setOrderby('starttime');
$query->setSortorder('ascending');
$query->setMaxResults(500);

$query->setSingleEvents("false");

$query->setStartMin('2010-06-01 00:00:00');
$query->setStartMax('2010-09-20 00:00:00');
$query->setQuery(/*title of the events*/);

return $gc->getCalendarEventFeed($query);
```

The resulting feed contains all 5 recurrences, and "canceled" event objects for all deleted instances up to `2010-07-15` where they arbitrarily stop. I should note that the `getWhen()` array on each recurrence contains the correct times (i.e. it omits the canceled dates) but due to the way my program is coded, it's important that I have access to the actual canceled event objects.

What could possibly be causing the API to not return all the canceled/modified events? Max results can't be the problem since there are only about 30 events in the feed. I'm basically out of ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm convinced this is a bug in the calendar API and I ended up writing a workaround for it.

I wrote code to calculate the expected instances of an event based on the start and recurrence data and then compare that against the instances in the `when` array on the recurrence. It creates canceled event objects when there is an expected instance but it's missing from the `when` array.